# Cannot infer type for `B` for filter_map().sum()

Tags: parsing, types, rust, type-inference

The code below reads numbers, sums them, then prints the sum. I've tried few annotations, but it didn't work. I must be missing something. How could I make it work?

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut buff = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buff).expect("read_to_string error");

    let v: i32 = buff
        .split_whitespace()
        .filter_map(|w| w.parse().ok())
        .sum();

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Error message from compiler:

```
type annotations needed
 --> src\main.rs:9:10
  |
9 |         .filter_map(|w| w.parse().ok())
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `B`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick fix is to say which type you are parsing into:

```
let v: i32 = buff
    .split_whitespace()
    .filter_map(|w| w.parse::<i32>().ok())
    .sum();
```

The reason is that `filter_map` has a type variable `B`, which would need to be inferred from the closure that you pass to it (the closure returns `Option<B>`). However, `parse()` also has a type variable for the type you are parsing into, which also can often be inferred. But here the type-checker would have to infer each of these types from each other, which obviously can't be done. To break the cycle, you have to tell it somewhere what the concrete type is.

You also could have fixed it by annotating `filter_map`. It's not as nice because `filter_map` has two type parameters, but you can still let the second one be inferred by using an `_`:

```
let v: i32 = buff
    .split_whitespace()
    .filter_map::<i32, _>(|w| w.parse().ok())
    .sum();
```

Comment: I was interpreting the compiler message as "I have to annotate `filter_map`", didn't occur to me it was about `parse`. Thanks.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation. You _could_ have annotated `filter_map` too, but it would be less pleasant to look at.

Comment: I was trying something like .filter_map<String,i32> before, confused me heh

Comment: @DulguunOtgon The second argument is a function type. Hence, best to infer it.

Comment: Pretty sure the `.ok()` is redundant as `Result` implements `IntoIterator` just like `Option`. Oh, that's if you switch to `flat_map`, nevermind. (I still prefer `flat_map`).

Answer (score 6):

Let's look up the signature of filter_map to see, what the complain is about:

```
fn filter_map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> FilterMap<Self, F> where F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> Option<B>,
```

Okay, so `Option<B>` is the result, which means he cannot infer what `w.parse().ok()` will be.

Let's try to give him a hint

```
.filter_map(|w| w.parse::<i32>().ok())
```

Let's compile an see.... Hurray!

So, lesson learned: Look up the signature and try to figure out, which part the compiler cannot infer and try to specify it.

Comment: We do write that `v : i32`, so why can't the compiler infer this?

Comment: Because you give that as a hint for the sum function. If you just write `let v = ...` you have to specify the type for sum `.sum::<i32>()`.

Comment: But if the compiler knows the type for `.sum`, why can't it then infer the type for `.parse`? Can `rustc` only make inferences on that level?

Comment: Because they could be different `w.parse::<u32>()` and `.sum::<u64>()` for example

Comment: @hellow: I don't think that is the reason. `w.parse::<u32>()` and `.sum::<u64>()` [will not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=51e381197289b22dea66b1b4b35b01df&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). I think it is more related to the fact that `sum()` does not return the summed type (call it `Item`) but any value that implements `Sum<Item>`. And that the compiler fails, because any number of types could apply.